# How to use additional fields in pivot table Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have two tables in relation users and projects. In users table I have addiotional field `admin_id`.

Pivot table is `project_user` with columns: `id, user_id, project_id and additonal field admin_id`

When I selecting projects from database I need also to check if `admin_id from pivot table` is `equal` with `admin_id from users table` is it possible???

Here is my User modal:

```
 public function projects(){
 return $this ->belongsToMany('App\Project','project_user')->withPivot('admin_id');
    }
```

Here is Controller:

```
 public function project(Project $project){
            //TAKING PROJECTS FORM CURRENT ID
            $projects = User::findOrFail(Auth::user() -> id) ;
            //NOT IMPORTANTE
            $users = User::lists('name','id');
            return view('projects',array('projects' => $projects,'users' => $users ));
        }
```

Blade:

```
@foreach($projects -> projects as $project)
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">{{ $project -> name }}</a>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found way....

This linke:

```
$projects = User::findOrFail(Auth::user() -> id) ;
```

Should be changed with this:

```
$projects = User::findOrFail(Auth::user() -> id)->projects()->where('admin_id', '=', $this->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to this documentation should give you what you need:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations

Specifically this section, which explains how you can add conditions to a relation query

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function($q)
{
    $q->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');

})->get();
```

Comment: Do you know how can I make query in my case?